# How to access SQLite Result Code within Data.execute with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

How can you get the SQLite result code when executing the Data.execute.  For example, I want to handle SQLite errors so the Smartface app does not fail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the SQLite result but if you have a syntax error in your sql statement(for example forgetting a comma, etc), Smartface will warn you about your error.

Comment: That's fine if its a syntax error but if its a result code due to data such as constraint issue then I can't handle this during coding since its a runtime issue